# MySQL won't start on Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, mysql

I'm getting this error while trying to start the mysql server

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --user=mysql
110425 23:11:33 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-e0-f8-47-0c-04-a0.lan.err'.
110425 23:11:33 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
110425 23:11:35 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-e0-f8-47-0c-04-a0.lan.pid ended
```

any suggestions?

Comment: There is no error there - what does the log say?

Comment: Which version of MySQL ?? v5.5.11 doesn't work (can't start) on Snow Leopard, but the old v5.1.56 do work (can start).

Comment: Check /var/log for mysql related logs and start trudging through them until you see some errors.

Comment: Could you please dump contents from `/usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-e0-f8-47-0c-04-a0.lan.err`? Looks like an error related to ethernet address binding, I guess.

Comment: @Rene: Mysql 5.5.11 (64 bit version) running here on Leopard (binary downloaded from mysql site) quite happily.

Comment: @nimrodm Yeah, it should work on Leopard, but not on Snow Leopard.

Comment: I've now got mysql 5.5.11 (64-bit) to run on my Snow Leopard, and it was a very stupid mistake of mine, that was the cause of the server not starting. I needed to modify my my.cnf file, so that the option "skip-locking" was changed to "skip-external-locking" - you can also just replace the file with one from `PATH_TO_MYSQL/mysql/support-files` (remember to rename the file to my.cnf).

Answer (score 1):

Change `skip-locking` to `skip-external-locking` in /etc/my.cnf.  This problem can happen if you had a different MySQL installed previously.  I experienced this problem when I moved to MAMP.